# SQL Server 2014 - How to get amount for Max Transaction Code

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, max

I have three tables Im joining to get results I need

1. Account Table
2. Contact Table
3. FinTrans table for Financial Transactions

With the below code, I get the AccountNumber, FullName, TransCode, TransNo and TransactionDate just fine and without errors. But now, I want to know the Amount for each Transaction Type from that list. But I seem to get multiple rows.
I have added extra code but commented those couple lines out to show what I want to add.

What do I need to add in the Group By section? I've tried adding TransNo, BusinessDay and then TransAmt. But I got multitple rows. I would really just like to show the TransAmt for that TransNo.

**My code so far:**

```
SELECT A.AccountNumber
      ,C.FirstName + ' ' + C.LastName Full_Name
      ,F.TransCode
      --,F.TransAmt
      ,MAX(TransNo)TransNo
      ,Cast(Max(BusinessDay) as Date) TransactionDate

FROM FinTrans F
INNER JOIN Account A ON F.AccounttID = A.AccountId
INNER JOIN Contact C ON F.AccountID = C.AccountId

WHERE F.TransCode IN ('Payment', 'Adjustment')
  AND F.AccountID IN (12345, 23456, 34567, 45678)

group by AccountNumber, FirstName, LastName, F.TransCode --, TransAmt

ORDER BY AccountNumber,TransactionDate
```

**EDIT:**
Adding the table sample data structure

```
Account Table Fields (A):
---------------------
AccountId
AccountNumber

Contact Table Fields (C):
---------------------
AccountId
FirstName
LastName

FinTrans Table fields (F):
------------------------
AccountId
TransCode
TransNo
TransAmt
BusinessDay


**A.AccountId = C.AccountId = F.AccountId**


FinTrans Table Data (F):
---------------------------------------------------
AccountId|TransCode |TransNo |TransAmt|BusinessDay|
--------------------------------------------------
12345    |Adjustment|A123456 |  545.26| 2018-04-11|
---------------------------------------------------
12345    |Payment   |P234567 |  125.14| 2018-04-10|
---------------------------------------------------
12345    |Payment   |P234566 |   99.26| 2018-04-08|
---------------------------------------------------
12345    |Adjustment|A356877 |   12.98| 2018-04-06|
---------------------------------------------------
```

**Expected Result:**

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
AccountNumber|Full_Name      |TransCode | TransAmt|TransNo  |BusinessDay|
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
A12345       |John Doe       |Adjustment|   545.26|A123456  | 2018-04-11|
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
A12345       |John Doe       |Payment   |   125.14|P234567  | 2018-04-10|
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: update your question add  a proper data sample and the expected  result

Comment: For us to accurately answer this, you need to provide us with a basic table structure and relationship.

Comment: I've edited the question and added table structure and expected result.

Comment: You say you want "Amount for each Transaction Type" but TransactionType isn't a column in any of your tables, so where is TransactionType in your database?

Comment: TransCode  is the term for Transaction Type. Please see 'Expected Result'.

Answer (score 0):

> Try this:
>
> SELECT A.AccountNumber    ,C.FirstName + ' ' + C.LastName
>   Full_Name,T.TransCode
>         ,F.TransAmt
>         ,T.TransNo
>         ,T.TransactionDate
>
> FROM (SELECT MAX(TransNo) TransNo,Cast(Max(BusinessDay) as Date)
>   TransactionDate, AccountId, TransCode FROM FinTrans WHERE TransCode IN
>   ('Payment', 'Adjustment') AND AccountID IN (12345, 23456, 34567,
>   45678)
>
> group by AccountId, TransCode) T
>
> INNER JOIN FinTrans F ON T.AccountID = F.AccountId and T.TransNo=F.TransNo
>   INNER JOIN Account A ON T.AccountID = A.AccountId
>   INNER JOIN Contact C ON T.AccountID = C.AccountId

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried adding the column to the transaction value?
SUM(F.TransAmt)

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer

Answer (score -1):

Look:

```
SELEC Name, Date, Value FROM x
```

Return

```
Jean 19-APR-2018 10
Jean 19-APR-2018 20
```

But

```
SELEC Name, Date, SUM(Value) FROM x GROUP BY Name
```

Will return

```
Jean 19-APR-2018 30
```

Comment: Rather than answering the same question twice, please just edit your first answer.